# glassfish dies and does not start again

Tags: bash, ubuntu, glassfish

One of our application servers (Glassfish v3.0.1) keeps crushing down with no reason. Sometimes, I am away from Internet so I cannot run it back again. Therefore, I wrote a simple bash script to wait for 10 minutes and then run asadmin. It is like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; 
do sleep 600;
sudo /home/ismetb/glassfishv3.0.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain; 
done
```

This seems to work fine however I have a couple of problems:

1. If I terminate the bash script (by pressing ctrl+z buttons), the Java process (Glassfish) dies and `start-domain` and `stop-domain` commands do not work at all. That means, I can neither stop Glassfish nor can I access it. I do not know if anybody else experienced this problem before or not. If the process dies, only thing I can do is to look for the ID of Java process and kill it from terminal. This not desirable at all. Any ideas why Java process dies when I quit script?
2. What I want to add to my script is something like to check the port Glassfish is using. If port is occupied maybe I can assume that Glassfish is not down! (However, the port (8080 default) might still be used by Glassfish although Glassfish is dead, I am not sure of it). If not, then with the help of a simple code, I can get the id of the Java process and kill them all. Then `start-domain` command will successfully work. Any ideas or any directions on how I can do this?

Comment: Ctrl+Z should not kill the script, simply suspend it. You can usually bring this programs to the for again with `fg` (foreground command).

Comment: Great! That was the case with ctrl+z, I will avoid it. However, when I run the server through asadmin (when I do not use bash script), the server still dies sometimes and does not respond to the start or stop commands. Although it is rare, it happens. So, #2 is still a valid problem for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`cron`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) job instead. To install a cron job for root, enter

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and add this line

```
*/10 * * * * /home/ismetb/glassfishv3.0.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain
```

This will run `asadmin` every ten minutes.

If you're not comfortable with the command line, you might also try `gnome-schedule`, but I have no experience with that.

For your second problem, you can use `curl` or `wget` to access glassfish. You can try to get some URL, or even access the administration interface, and if you don't get a response, assume glassfish is down.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Olaf. I used `crontab -e` command and added the line you provided.

Comment: @iso_9001_ Good to see, you figured it out by yourself. I updated my answer, just in case.